# SQLAlchemy query a chain of One-to-Many relationships

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to query a chain of one-to-many relationships in SQLAlchemy. Given the following models (Base is a declarative base):

```
class Book(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chapters = relationship("Chapter", backref="book")

class Chapter(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Book.id))
    pages = relationship("Page", backref="chapter", lazy="dynamic")

class Page(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chapter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Chapter.id))
```

I need to query the Page entities by the Book they are associated with (through the Chapter). However,

```
Page.query.filter(Page.chapter.book_id == 1)
```

doesn't work in this case. The number of Pages is quite big (hence the `lazy="dynamic"` parameter when querying Chapters), and I'd like not to de-normalize by adding a `book_id` column to the Page table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qry = Page.query.join(Chapter).join(Book).filter(Book.id == 1)
```